# Disable sticky option for specific categories

Tags: posts, categories, theme-development

Is there a way to disable the sticky option on posts in specific categories?

Comment: Maybe, yes. What did you find in your research?

Comment: Nothing, that's the problem. I keep getting pages of irrelevant search results.

Comment: Maybe there's nothing more to say about it, but I find strange a one line Question with `the_title == the_content`... Much probably this is a jQuery [solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59074/12615), I've answered quite a [few](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12615+%2Bjquery). And an inside research on [*Sticky Posts*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sticky+post%22+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with another approach. I check to see what the current user's role is, then if the role is 'author', enqueued a CSS file to hide the sticky option's checkbox.

In the theme's functions.php file:

```
function hide_sticky_option($hook) {
    global $current_user;

    if('post.php'== $hook || 'post-new.php'==$hook){
        $role = array_shift($current_user->roles); //get role of current user
        if($role=='author'){ //if role of current user is 'author'
            wp_enqueue_style('hide_sticky_option', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-post-style.css' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'hide_sticky_option' );
```

admin-post-style.css:

```
#sticky-span {
    display:none !important;
}
```